# Mobaxterm: Connect through SSH gateway (jump host) gives Error as "Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection"

Tags: ssh, remote-server, mobaxterm

I am using Mobaxterm to ssh to customer servers but from a jump host.

The Option which works fine:

when I open mobaxterm --> create a new ssh connection --> enter the hostname (jump host in my case) and username --> and when I try to connect to this session, it works fine and then I need to manually ssh to customer servers after I get connected to jump host.

The Option which does not work:

when I open mobaxterm --> create a new ssh connection --> enter the customer hostname --> under Network setting --> I enable "Connect through SSH gateway (jump host) and enter jump server hostname and username --> save the session.
When I try to connect to this session, it gives error as `"Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection".`

Can someone assist to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you confuse which one to be added as the jump host. As an example, I will use `3.45.67.89` jump host to connect to `192.168.0.100` target host.

Create a new session, and:

1. Add `192.168.0.100` as your remote host. Specify username and port if necessary.
2. In *Advanced SSH settings* tab, check *Use private key* and insert the credentials for the target host
3. Go to *Network settings* tab and configure your jump host by clicking the *SSH gateway (jump host)* button
4. Add `3.45.67.89` jump host to one of the jump hosts without forgetting the jump host credentials. Specify username and port.
5. Click OK and then OK again

If nothing is wrong the SSH connection should work like there's no jump host.

TLDR; the jump host should be added to *SSH gateway (jump host)*, not as a remote host.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Mobaxterm
2. go to Settings menu> click configuration
   dialogue box will appear go to SSH tab in that
3. In the second Section( SSH Settings) enable the checkbox SSH Keepalive and Fix Connection issues
4. Click OK to save the configuration.
5. SSH to the server now !!! enjoy